# Using Access VBA to get varchar OUTPUT parameter from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures, ms-access-2010

I have the following stored procedure in SQL server and can call it just fine from within SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspRecipeNote
    @IngString varchar(255) OUTPUT,
    @MixID int = NULL
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @IngString = dbo.ufnRecipeNote(@MixID);
```

I have been using VBA in Access to call stored procedures for months and have never had a problem, but have tried several possibilities and am stumped, getting either of the following errors, depending upon what I have tried:

"Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided."
"Procedure or function uspRecipeNote has too many arguments specified."

Here is what I have at this point in VBA:

```
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "uspRecipeNote"

'add parameters
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@IngString", adVarChar, adParamOutput)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@MixID", adInteger, adParamInput, , intMixID)

cmd.Execute
```

I get an error on the first parameter no matter what I have tried. I suspect it is something simple. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried putting the output parameter last instead of first in the SP?

Comment: Yes, that is my typical practice, but I switched them as one of my attempts to make it work.

Comment: When I type in what you have above, VBA automatically inserts a ";" as follows:
     Debug.Print cn.Execute; "uspRecipeNote " & intMixID

Comment: No problem. I have tried several options using parentheses, to no avail. When I try what you have listed above, I get "Procedure or function 'uspRecipeNote' expects parameter '@MixID', which was not supplied."

Comment: Also you can use `Execute` instead `ADODB.Commands` and put into record set `Dim rs as New ADODB.Recordset` and then `rs = connection_name.Execute ("EXEC uspRecipeNote @IngString OUTPUT, " & intMixID & ";")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String parameters need to be defined with a (maximum) length, e.g.,

```vbs
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@IngString", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 255)
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I have tried that, I get the error: "Procedure or function uspRecipeNote has too many arguments specified." Does this provide a clue?

Comment: It did get past adding the parameter, but now fails at "cmd.Execute" with the error just above.

Comment: I dunno, I just tried it (code [here](http://pastebin.com/EPkLeWww)) and it works for me. Is it possible that somewhere along the line `@IngString` got mixed up with `@lngString`? Or maybe there are multiple versions of `uspRecipeNote` under different schemas?

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a problem with my command object, which I was reusing, as I have many times before. This time I failed to clear it properly, which explains some of the odd behavior, like "too many arguments." Oh, the joys...

Comment: Ah, okay. Reusing ADODB.Command objects is not a recommended practice as strangeness may ensue, and not just for that reason (as I recall).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who helped try to solve my problem. It turns out that it was a problem with my command object, not the SP or the VBA (except for needing the length for the varchar parameter - thanks, Gord). Everything works just fine now!